# Or-tools java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform

Tags: java, eclipse, linear-programming, or-tools

Hi I'm trying to run this [sample code](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/java/LinearProgramming.java) on my eclipse ide and have manually adding the jars file without using the pom file provided but it's complaining with this error.

I managed to compile and run the sample code using 'make run' command.

Any idea is it possible to copy the library jar files and use it in my own project in eclipse?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use a maven pom file. Don't try and manually add jar files. Also, you may need a much older version of Java to work with your specific tools. Oracle bought Sun Microsystems twelve years ago. Anything that uses `com.sun` is likely to be quite old.

Comment: The reason why I want to manually add the jar files is because I want to create my own project. Can I copy the pom file provided into my own project and use it directly?

Comment: Of course you can!  (Edit it as required ...)

Comment: The JNA `Platform` class should be in the jna-platform-5.5.jar.  So this suggests there is a problem with the classpath used when running.  But use Maven first and see if that sorts out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same issue but a similar one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/unix/LibCAPI$size_t$ByReference
```

And I was able to solve it by adding the following dependency in the pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Could be a good idea to check the documentation to find which version works fine to your project.

I hope this helps.

Happy Coding;